# R Shiny - Get placeholder value from fileInput

Tags: r, shiny, alert, shinyjs

I am able to read the placeholder value as a popup alert with the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode_upload_txt <- " Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('upload_txt', function(txt) {
  var target = $('#fileUpload').parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=text]');
  target.val(txt);
}); "

jscode_get_txt <- " Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('get_txt', 
  function(message) {
    var target = $('#fileUpload').parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=text]');
    alert(JSON.stringify(target.val()));
  }
); "

ui <- fluidPage( 
  tags$script(HTML(jscode_upload_txt)),
  tags$script(HTML(jscode_get_txt)),
  fileInput("fileUpload",  "File to upload", placeholder = "Initial Text") 
)

server <- function(input, output, session ) {
  showLog()
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("upload_txt", "SOME OTHER TEXT")
    session$sendCustomMessage("get_txt" , "")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I read it (and interact with it) directly in R? I tried `logjs` instead of `alert`, but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
jscode_get_txt <- " Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('get_txt', 
  function(message) {
    var target = $('#fileUpload').parent().parent().parent().find('input[type=text]');
    Shiny.setInputValue('placeholder', target.val());
  }
); "
```

then the placeholder is available in `input$placeholder`.